# VBA regex - How to exclude special characters

Tags: regex, ms-access, vba

I'm new to regex and I'm trying to exclude certain special characters from the replace function below.

```
Function removeAlpha(r As String) As String
With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
   .Pattern = "\D+"
    .Global = True
    removeAlpha = .Replace(r, "")
End With
End Function
```

Currently it's stripping out every single non-numeric within the string and leaving me with numbers.

However i want it to ignore the following characters **- , .**

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include them in negated character class like this.

**Regex:** `[^\d,.-]+` This will match not match more than one numeric, comma, dot and hyphen. `\D` is same as `[^\d]`

**Note:-** Always keep `-` at beginning or at end in a character class.